react i18n transalation files issue
I am trying i18n in react. I have files structure like below
src/i18n/i18n.js => Part of this file is below
import Backend from "i18next-http-backend";

 await i18n
    .use(Backend) // We use this to load the translation files dynamically
    .use(initReactI18next) // React bindings
    .init({
      debug: true,
      resources: {},
      fallbackLng: "en", // Default fallback language
      missingKeyHandler: (lng, ns, key, fallbackValue) => {
        console.log(`Missing key: ${key} in ${lng}`);
        return fallbackValue || `Missing translation for ${key}`;
      },
      lng: language, // Set the initial language
      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false, // No escaping needed
      },
      ns: ["translation"], // Default namespace is 'translation'
      defaultNS: "translation", // Specify default namespace
      backend: {
        loadPath: "/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json", // Path to load language files
        allowMultiLoading: false,
        request: function (options) {
          // Disable caching for testing
          options.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
          return fetch(options.url, options);
        },
      },
      react: {
        useSuspense: false, // Disable React Suspense for dynamic loading
      },

      // resources: {
      //   en: {
      //     translation: {
      //       welcome_message: "Welcome to our app!",
      //     },
      //   },
      //   es: {
      //     translation: {
      //       welcome_message: "¡Bienvenido a nuestra aplicación!",
      //     },
      //   },
      // },
      load: "languageOnly", // Load only the language files (e.g., translation.json)
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("i18next initialized successfully");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error initializing i18next:", error);
    });

public/locales/en/translation.json
public/locales/fr/translation.json
{
  "header": {
    "welcome_message": "Welcome to our app!"
  }
}

Issue that I am facing is when I access {t("header.welcome_message")} in my component then its not getting translated or showing that message. Just showing like header.welcome_message
I checked by accessing url http://localhost:3000/locales/en/translation.json , it shows data of that file.
also checked statically in resources which is working.
It's not working dynamically with files.
My console shows like below

What is missing or getting wrong ? Please help and guide.
